# Azure Active directory SSO not generating roles in authtoken

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, single-sign-on, express-jwt

I am trying to do Single Sign on using AAD I have decoded the JWT token that I obtain after logging in. However, the token is missing the roles that I believe are required for backend authentication.

Below is the reference that I have tried.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-apps

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-tutorial/tree/main/3-Authorization-II/1-call-api

Additionally, if you could send me a reference for securing the API with node JS and angular login, that would be a huge help.

Answer (score 0):

> **Note** that: When you create App roles it creates application type roles, and to display these roles in access token you have to make use of server-to-server authorization (Client credential flow) flow.

As you are making use of SPA authentication where user interaction is involved, check the below:

I created an **Azure AD SPA application** and exposed an API:

[image]

Grant Admin consent for the scope in API permissions blade:

[image]

I used the below endpoint to **authorize users**:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=api://ClientID/.default
&state=12345
&code_challenge=CodeChallenge
&code_challenge_method=S256
```

[image]

[image]

Generated **access token** via Postman by using below parameters:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenanTID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
scope:api://ClientID/.default
grant_type:authorization_code
code:code
code_verifier:S256
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
```

[image]

***When decoded the token, scopes are displayed:***

[image]

To know how to do the same in Angular and node.js, refer this [Angular SPA and Node.js API with Azure AD for authentication (SSO) | by FluentJS](https://fluentjs.medium.com/angular-spa-and-node-js-api-with-azure-ad-for-authentication-in-2021-b2974666c2eb)

**Reference:**

[Code samples for Microsoft identity platform authentication and authorization - Microsoft Entra](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v2-code?tabs=apptype)